# How to pass results from one source stream to another

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a method that processes a `Source` and returns. I am trying to modify it but can't seem to be able to return the same thing:

Original

```
def originalMethod[as: AS, mat: MAT, ec: EC](checkType: String) 
: Flow[ByteString, MyValidation[MyClass], NotUsed]{
      collectStuff
      .map { ts =>
        val errors = MyEngine.checkAll(ts.code)
        (ts, errors)
      }
      .map { x =>
        x._2
          .leftMap(xs => {
            addInformation(x._1, xs.toList)
          })
          .toEither
      }
}
```

I am modifying by using another source and pass result of that to the original source and yet return the same thing:

```
def calculate[T: AS: MAT](source: Source[T, NotUsed]): Future[Seq[T]] = 
{
 source.runWith(Sink.seq)
}


def modifiedMethod[as: AS, mat: MAT, ec: EC](checkType: String, mySource: Source[LoanApplicationRegister, NotUsed]) 
: Flow[ByteString, MyValidation[MyClass], NotUsed]{
  for {
    calc <- calculate(mySource)
    orig <-  collectStuff
        .map { ts =>
          val errors = MyEngine.checkAll(ts.code, calc)
          (ts, errors)
        }
        .map { x =>
          x._2
            .leftMap(xs => {
              addInformation(x._1, xs.toList)
            })
            .toEither
        }
  }
  yield {
    orig
  }
}
```

But I'm getting compilation error `Expression of type Future[Nothing] doesn't conform to existing type Flow[ByteString, MyValidation[MyClass]`

How can I return `Flow[ByteString, MyValidation[MyClass]` in my `modifiedMethod` just like the `originalMethod` was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  for { calc <- calculate(mySource)}
  yield {
    collectStuff
        .map { ts =>
          val errors = MyEngine.checkAll(ts.code, calc)
          (ts, errors)
        }
        .map { x =>
          x._2
            .leftMap(xs => {
              addInformation(x._1, xs.toList)
            })
            .toEither
        }
  }
```

would give you a `Future[Flow[ByteString, MyValidation[MyClass], NotUsed]]` instead of `Future[Nothing]`
but if you want to remove the `Future` you'd need to `Await` somewhere for it (either when you call calculate (and then you don't need the `for`) or after it. Usually, that's not the way to use Futures

Comment: I see, you're suggesting that the method returns `Future[Flow[ByteString, MyValidation[MyClass], NotUsed]]` instead of `Flow[ByteString, MyValidation[MyClass], NotUsed]`

Comment: If I wrap `calculate` in an `onComplete` and then run the part that is in yield, will it be guaranteed to run AFTER the `onComplete` finishes?

Comment: the `modifiedMethod` is being called from somewhere like this: `rawData(id).take(1).via(modifiedMethod(checkType, mySource).zip(Source.fromIterator() => Iterator.from(1))).collect{...}` . If I return a `Future` the part where the method is called from complains with `expected Graph[FlowShape[ByteString, NotInferedT], NotInferedMat2] actual: Future[Flow[ByteString, MyValidation[MyClass], NotUsed]` Is there a way around this?

Comment: you may avoid the Future by returning a having the calculation as part as another step in the flow (e.g. execute it with Flow[Seq[T]].mapAsync or something like that - though you should probably ask that in a different question with more detials)

Comment: I have a separate question to see how to return Future from this method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53799829/modify-via-to-accept-method-returning-a-future