# Modify via to accept method returning a Future

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am calling a method using `via` like below:

```
myRawStr(id)
.take(1)
.via(myMethod("someString", someSource)
.zip(Source.fromIterator(() => Iterator.from(1)))
.collect {
...
}
```

`myMethod` returns type `Flow[ByteString, MyValidated[MyClass], NotUsed]` but now it will be returning `Future[Flow[ByteString, MyValidated[MyClass], NotUsed]]` (**Note**: Future)

but doing this gives me compilation error on `via`. The error states:

```
[error]  found   : [as, mat, ec]scala.concurrent.Future[akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[akka.util.ByteString,MyValidated[MyClass],akka.NotUsed]]
[error]     (which expands to)  [as, mat, ec]scala.concurrent.Future[akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[akka.util.ByteString,scala.util.Either[List[ValidationError],MyClass],akka.NotUsed]]
[error]  required: akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.FlowShape[akka.util.ByteString,?],?]
[error]       .via(myMethod("someString", someSource))
[error]
```

How can I modify this to accept a `Future` OR [based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53799124/how-to-pass-results-from-one-source-stream-to-another) return a non future by adding another step in the flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`via` accepts a `Flow` as argument. You either have to change `MyMethod` to return a `Flow` instead of a `Future`. Or instead of using `via` you can use `mapAsyc` that maps your flow using a method that returns a `Future` (MyMethod):

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/mapAsync.html